# How to call Typescript method in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

We have a typescript class,which contains few methods. Sample example of the TypeScript class.

```
 export class AppointmentListComponent implements OnInit {
    editEvent(event: IEvent): void {
        this._router.navigate(['/appointments', event.id]);
    }
 }
```

We want to call editEvent method from another (.js) file.
How can we achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427722/calling-properly-typescript-code-from-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling properly TypeScript code from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427722/calling-properly-typescript-code-from-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

If you are working with ES6 it's pretty simple. In typescript just use `import "pathToJSModule";` and you are ready to use it. This is possible because JS is a valid Typescript.

If you are not working with ES6 you can use `import * as foo from "pathToFile"`.

Comment: That's the wrong way round. OP wants to use TypeScript code from JavaScript, not JavaScript code from TypeScript