# Is it possible to call Typescript Method in HTML Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Webprojekt with FireBaseCloudMessaging running. Now i have to call a Method in a Typescript File to reload the Messages on Notification. Is this Possible?

**HTML Part (index.html)**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        // ChatDialog.reloadMessages(); <-- Here i have to call the Typescript Method
    });
</script>
```

**ChatDialog.ts**

```
//This is the Method i have to call!
    reloadMessages(){
        this.messages.removeAll();
        localStorage.clear();
        ChatFunctions.getMessages(this, this.partner_id);
    }
```

Comment: How are you compiling your TS code? Do you use modules? Post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Iam using **NPM** and **Bower**! Iam compiling my Typescript whit **grunt**! HTML to Typescript is handled whit **Knockout** and Typescript to HTML via **JQuery and Ajax**

Comment: Typescript is compiled to JS, so it's definitely possible – just like calling any method in JS. This might help you to find your way around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427722/calling-properly-typescript-code-from-javascript

Comment: When iam calling it `new ChatDialog().reloadMessages()` it throws an error: `Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.`.