# How to call JavaScript functions from Typescript in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm working on PDF Viewer development in Angular 5. I'm done with writing HTML code for the UI part. Now I've JavaScript files that provide functionality for the UI elements. As Angular 5 supports typescript for implementing functionality for UI components, I want to include JavaScript files in Angular Project and call them from my Typescript code.

Questions:

1. How and where to include JavaScript Files in Angular Project?
2. How to call the JavaScript Functions from Typescript class?

It would be great if anyone provides me an example.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**1. How and where to include JavaScript Files in Angular Project?**

You need to include your **JS** file in the *asset* folder and refer this JS file in **.angular-cli.json** file.

Refer the snapshot's,

*Folder structure should be like this.*

[image]

*.angular-cli.json*

[image]

**2. How to call the JavaScript Functions from Typescript class?**

*your TS should be like this.*

[image]

*myJsFile.js file content.*

[image]

This sample logic mentioned above will work, I have tried and tested using version 4, So I am expecting it to work with version 5 also.

> Updating the answer for the new Angular version release. Working
> perfectly till version `11.2.6`.

**Find the code (function with parameter) [here](https://github.com/ArunRaj6/invoke-js-function-from-angular) for Angular11**

Comment: Working with angular 6 too

Comment: I wonder about the performance. Does include Js file in angular.json the best way. does it loaded and ready for all component to call. in fact you use declare function:any is kind of weird, it means i can call the function like that in other component too right? won't it affect the performance?

Comment: If you really worried about the perfomance & declaration syntax in the component(one/multiple). You can go for TypesScript declaration files. Conside this sample example: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3169-adding-custom-typings-files-d-ts-in-an-angular-2-typescript-application.htm

Comment: How to pass any parameter in the same method of external file?

Comment: Works for Angular 8. Only change is, instead of .angular-cli.json its just angular.json

Comment: Please check the latest update in my answer with an example of Angulr8.

Comment: How to call function having parameters from .js file in .ts file? @ArunRajR

Comment: Working perfectly with Angular 10 and 11 too.

Comment: @YeshaShah passing the parameters is explained in Shashikant Devani answer.

Comment: Works great with Ang8. No tweaks required except for the json file name

Comment: I was getting an error saying the JS function is not defined, but it's working now after restarting my localhost server.

Answer (score 16):

The given [answer by Arun Raj R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49527992/8358892) is perfect.

But for the **angular 6+** project you need to take `angular.json` instead of `angular-cli.json`.

also if you want to pass parameter inside external function that come from js file than use just `function name`.

For Ex :

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare function myfunction: any; // just change here from arun answer.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { 
        myfunction('test1', 'test2');
    }
};
```

**yourJs file :**

```
function myfunction(params1, params2) {
    console.log('param1', params1);
    console.log('param2', params2);
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me. I had to pass one parameter. This didn't show any error but that function isn't alerted

Comment: Hope, you added that javascript file inside the angular.json. also stop running the ng serve and again start it. So angular cli fetch updated angular.json

Comment: Yes sorry not to update my comment. I had to add the myscript.js file location in <script> tag of my index.html. That way it worked. Thanks @Shashikanth

Comment: instead of "var", you should write "function" keyword.

Comment: How to call function having parameters from .js file in .ts file?@ShashikantDevani

Comment: @YeshaShah yeah I need the same and seems it is not working

Comment: @YeshaShah, Use `var` instead of `function`. Like this `declare var myfunction: any;`

Comment: @YeshaShah, Hope you had added your custom created js file in `scripts` in `angular.json`. Like this `src/assets/js/custom.js`. If you added custom.js path in running project than restart project `(ng serve or npm start)` after adding anything in `angular.json`.

Comment: typescript complains about that. Using `declare function myfunction(param1: string, param2: string): any;` worked..

Comment: declare function myfunction: any; doesn't work in type script neither declare function myfunction(param1: string, param2: string): any;

Comment: declare function myfunction(parameter1: any): any; works