# Can't import Thrift-generated Typescript into Angular 7 Project

Tags: angular, typescript, thrift

I am new to typescript and need help getting a thrift-generated module to import into my Angular 7 project. I get an error when I compile:

> ERROR in src/app/user.service.ts(5,33): error TS2306: File
>   '/Users/xxxx/projects/tct-client/src/app/gen-js/TestModule_types.d.ts'
>   is not a module.

The thrift:

```
  namespace js Test
  struct TestModuleClass
  {
    1: required string somestring
  }
```

The generated typescript:

```
  declare module Test {
    class TestModuleClass {
      somestring: string;

        constructor(args?: { somestring: string; });
    }
  }
```

The import line:

```
  import { TestModuleClass } from './gen-js/TestModule_types';
```

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526681/how-to-call-javascript-functions-from-typescript-in-angular-5