# How to use Panzoom javascript in Angular 8+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, panzoom

I am unable to use [Panzoom Javascript library](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom) in Angular. I get

```
ERROR
Error: panzoom is not defined
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsxhcb) of what i have done till now .
Here is the [working demo](https://anvaka.github.io/panzoom/demo/dom.html) of how it should work

Can any one help me troubleshoot ? Thanks

I have followed all the steps mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49527992/5724889)

Comment: Perhaps https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-panzoom this package will help?

Comment: @penleychan nope, it's different library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems Panzoom does have typescript definitions [Github Issue](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom/issues/108)

here is  a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrof7z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import panzoom from "panzoom";

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<img id="scene" #scene src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">`,
  styles: []
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('scene', { static: false }) scene: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // panzoom(document.querySelector('#scene'));
    panzoom(this.scene.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: getting this error for your example in my application. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: wrap it around `if(this.scene)` maybe your code is executing before the element is loaded into dom i am doing it in ngAfterview Init you can also test by using setTimeout

Comment: nice! that was easy

Comment: There is a bug when increases to 150% and then decreases - it continues to increase one more time.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to do this.

1. Open your angular project in cmd terminal (root of your project, the same foler which contains /src).
2. Type `npm install panzoom --save` (that will add `panzoom` npm package to your `angular.json` and install it).
3. In your component add import `import * as panzoom from "panzoom"` (your project should automaticaly link it with the right file from node_modules.
4. in ngOnInit or anywhere needed add this line `panzoom.default(document.querySelector('#lipsum'));`

You should generally incject this `PanZoom` package in your component constructor after importing it from node_modules but I'm not sure if there is an integration provided by an author.

Definitely check [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/panzoom) documentation of this plugin for more info