# Calling Typescript function from JavaScript file in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a plain old `.js` file that draws svg on my Angular component.
I have some events in that file and I want to call functions defined in my component code from that `.js` file.

I haven't found any solution to this problem? Is this achievable? If yes how?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777225/calling-an-angular-component-method-from-classic-html/61778035#61778035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can create a custom event in javascript and "listen" in your Angular app, but **I'm not prety sure if this work**

To create a custom event in javascript see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

```
var event = new Event('build',{ data: 'hello word' });
// Dispatch the event.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

To listen the event in Angular, use fromEvent rxjs

```
ngOnInit()
{
    fromEvent(window,'build').subscribe(event=>{
       console.log(event.data)
    })
}
```