# Angular 16, how make reactive form recognize an input change when the element was changed using getElementById('value').value

Tags: angular

How make reactive form recognize an input change when the element was changed using getElementById('value').value = 'some value' in a script on the index.html file? I need to do this because otherwise I will have an endless work, and the project is just a prototype. later I can improve my code. In the prototype stage I cannot fine tune things, it's just the way things are.

Comment: You can't, _it's just the way things are_ . What you can do is build a proper prototype using what Angular provides you.

Answer (score 2):

Really you **should use** [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue) method

```
<input id="id" formControlName="id">

//if your form is "form"
this.form.get('id').setValue("something")
```

Well, You can use plain javaScript in the way

```
//get the element
const el=document.getElementById('id') as HTMLInputElement
//change the value
el.value="some more"
//create an event "input"
const event = new Event('input');
//and Dispatch it.
el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

But, really you should have a good, good reason to use javaScript for this

NOTE: You can take also this [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081958/calling-typescript-function-from-javascript-file-in-angular/62082111#62082111) to call a function in typescript from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular you should use what Angular provides since it is a framework and not just a library.

This is a proper way to use **valueChanges**:

```
this.yourForm
      ?.get(yourFormName)
      ?.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
        // do whatever you need
      })
```

If you wrap this in a method, make sure to call it in the `ngOnInit()` method **AFTER** you initialize your form.