# How to listen for javascript callback in an Angular 16 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to integrate my Angular 16 app with a 3rd party site using an iFrame. My questions is how to capture the callback response from their site?

The suggested way to integrate with their API from an html page is to use an iframe as follows:

```
<iframe
        id='iframe'
        src='<%=theirURL %>'
        allowfullscreen
        style="width:80%; height:800px;"
        ></iframe>
```

After the user completes some steps in the iframe, it should call back to this script:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    function receiveMessage(event) {
        console.log(event);
        //I want to call my angular function with the event from here    
    }</script>
```

I was able to get the iframe to load by doing this in my component.ts file:

```
ngAfterViewChecked () {
  var myElement = document.getElementById("myiframe");
  if (myElement !== null) {
    document.getElementById("myiframe").setAttribute("src",this.iFrameURL);
  }
}
```

And this in my component.html file:

```
<iframe
    id='myiframe'
    allowfullscreen
    style="width:80%; height:800px;"
    >
</iframe>
```

But Angular removes script /script tags.
How can I listen for the callback function and then call my angular function with the event data?

I have a tried a few different things.

1. This gave an error: I suspect it was because the .js file was not found. But the error said: Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. None of my console.log messages were logged in the console.

In the constructor for the component:

```
    this.myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    this.myScriptElement.type="text/javascript";
    this.myScriptElement.src = "./myfile.js";
    document.body.appendChild(this.myScriptElement);
```

In myfile.js (which was in the same directory as the component):

```
    window.onload = function () {
      console.log('adding event listener in window.onload');
      window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    }

function receiveMessage(event) {
    console.log(event);
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

It didn't get this far, but inside the component I had:

```
  @HostListener('window:MessageEvent', ['$event.detail'])
  onCallAngularService (detail: any) {
    //a call to my angular function
  }
```

2. I tried putting the .js file in angular.json and in the assets folder
   "scripts": [ "src/assets/myfile.js" ],
   And then I wasn't sure what to do in the component.
   I added this:
   declare function receiveMessage(): void;

But that's as far as I got. The window.onload function doesn't appear to run on page load.

Comment: I don't know if works with iframes, but you can try use some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081958/calling-typescript-function-from-javascript-file-in-angular/62082111#62082111)

Comment: Thanks @eliseo. I also saw this. But I'm to figure out how to apply it. My event never seems to fire. https://www.javachinna.com/call-angular-function-from-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue, here's how I got it working:

Here's how I got it to work:

1. I put the javascript file in my assets folder
2. I added it in angular.json under scripts
3. In tsconfig.json, I added
   `"allowJs": true, // allow js scripts usage inside the project`
4. in the javascript file,

```
    function receiveMessage(event) {
      window.angularComponentReference.zone.run(() => { 
      window.angularComponentReference.loadAngularFunction(event.data); });        
    }

export function addMyListener() { 
  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
}
```

5. In my component

   a) import * as myscript from "../../assets/myscript.js"

   b) iFrameAlreadyLoaded = false; //create variable and default to false. To make sure iFrame only loads once.

   c) in ngOnInit

```
    myscript.addMyListener(); 
    window['angularComponentReference'] = { component: this, zone: this.ngZone, loadAngularFunction: (value: any) => this.myAngularFunctionName(value), };
```

d) also in componenent.ts

```
    if (!this.iFrameAlreadyLoaded) {
      var myElement = document.getElementById("myiframe");
      if (myElement !== null) {
        document.getElementById("myiframe").setAttribute("src",this.iFrameURL); //set the iframe source
        this.iFrameAlreadyLoaded = true;
      }
    }
  }
```