# How to implement Fabricjs Align guidelines in Angular?

Tags: angular, fabricjs

We are trying to implement the FabricJs Guidelines-(Aligning, Snapping) as per the link: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js

These are steps, we followed (as per link : [How to call JavaScript functions from Typescript in Angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526681/how-to-call-javascript-functions-from-typescript-in-angular-5)):

Step 1: Copied these js's into the assets/folder as guidelines.services.js

Step 2: Declared those functions on .ts files

**ISSUE:** Still facing issues - delay in loading shapes in implementing it.

Kindly help us with relevant Demo/ implementation /Documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned above steps are right, except they need to be initialized at `ngAfterContentInit()`.
Codes will be like this.

```
//#region Methods which are defined in the .js files.

declare function initCenteringGuidelines(canvas: fabric.Canvas):void;
declare function initAligningGuidelines(canvas: fabric.Canvas):void;
declare function initKeyBoardMovement (canvas: fabric.Canvas,e:any):void;

//#endregion

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fabric-canvas',
  templateUrl: './fabric-canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fabric-canvas.component.scss'],
})


ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.eventHandler.canvas) {
        this.eventHandler.canvas.dispose();
      }
      this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
        selection: true,
        preserveObjectStacking: true,
        backgroundColor:'#2d2d2d', //need to add to Theme,
        fireRightClick: true,  // <-- enable firing of right click events
        fireMiddleClick: true, // <-- enable firing of middle click events
        stopContextMenu: true, // <--  prevent context menu from showing
      });

    
      initCenteringGuidelines(this.canvas);
      initAligningGuidelines(this.canvas);   
    });
  }
```