# How to call a typescript function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function in my TypeScript file:

```
public test(): string[] {
    return new Array("Mary", "Tom", "Jack", "Jill");
}
```

How do I call this function from JavaScript?

Comment: You create the class and invoke the method .. just as you normally would .. complications might arise if you use a module system but that is a general JS issue not so much TS

Comment: `test()`.......

Comment: You need to compile the Typescript to Javascript first anyway. Once you do, it's just like any other Javascript.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript) could be interesting for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling properly TypeScript code from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427722/calling-properly-typescript-code-from-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript files are source files that are not run directly, they are transpiled to JavaScript before they can be run. Normally project using TypeScript have some sort of build pipeline setup using something like Webpack, you cannot just use a TypeScript file directly with a JavaScrpt project.

Comment: So what can we do now? I need to get the list of data from the vscode extension (typescript) to vscode webview script part (javascript).

Comment: That is not in your question. So to get a better answer, include all code so that others can reproduce your situation.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript before anything else happens - so once it's compiled, you call it later in your project just like you would any other function:

```
test();
```

Comment: actually i guess i have to import the .js file which is a compiled .ts file but writing that in script part of html is really not working