# How to use export typescript class in js code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I've developed a PWA and I need to add a custom service worker to sync the client database data with server database. I did a search and I found examples in  JavaScript.

My first question is: is there a way to write my custom service worker in typescript?

If no, is there a way to use type script class in a JavaScript file? I followed this link:

[Calling properly TypeScript code from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427722/calling-properly-typescript-code-from-javascript)

But I use DI in my TS classes and pass instance to constructor. How can I use these classes in JavaScript?

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: I use angular 6 with .net core

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438163/11912521